# how to find if edit box got the focus

Tags: python, focus, pywinauto

I need to verify that the focus moves to some edit box after typing "ENTER"
in other edit box.
I'am using pywinauto library.
I tried using 'has_keyboard_focus()' but it always returns 'False' no matter where 
the focus is.

```
o = dlg.child_window(title="UUT1", auto_id="gbUUT", control_type="Group"). \
child_window(title="Serial # 2 :",  control_type="Edit").has_keyboard_focus()
print(o)
```

Comment: Sorry, can't answer fast. Need to take a look.

Comment: If I click on an edit box, `.has_keyboard_focus()` returns True for me. What is the value returned by `.is_keyboard_focusable()`? Is method `.draw_outline()` highlighting the correct control?